# 9dof razor and BLE mini

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to transmit data from the 9dof Razor IMU module (from Sparkfun) via the BLE mini (Red Bear labs) to the BLEChat_Central_OSX app and it doesn't work :/

The codes I use are:

- https://github.com/ptrbrtz/razor-9dof-ahrs/tree/master/Arduino/Razor_AHRS
- https://github.com/RedBearLab/iOS/tree/master/Examples/BLEChat_Central_OSX

I tried to transmit via BLE only one value with following code:

```
     Serial.print(int(smoothedAX));

     Serial.println();
```

But when running the BLEChat on Xcode I receive only "i" and "Y" values:

```
2014-07-16 18:27:01.389 BLEChat Central[395:303] scanForPeripheralsWithServices

2014-07-16 18:27:02.108 BLEChat Central[395:303] didDiscoverPeripheral

2014-07-16 18:27:02.426 BLEChat Central[395:303] Duplicate UUID found updating...

2014-07-16 18:27:03.389 BLEChat Central[395:303] Stopped Scanning

2014-07-16 18:27:03.389 BLEChat Central[395:303] Known peripherals : 1

2014-07-16 18:27:03.389 BLEChat Central[395:303] List of currently known peripherals :

2014-07-16 18:27:03.390 BLEChat Central[395:303] 0  |  308B4C0E-F756-434C-84D4-B474B1C12AD6

2014-07-16 18:27:03.390 BLEChat Central[395:303]
------------------------------------

2014-07-16 18:27:03.390 BLEChat Central[395:303] Peripheral Info :

2014-07-16 18:27:03.390 BLEChat Central[395:303] UUID : 308B4C0E-F756-434C-84D4-B474B1C12AD6

2014-07-16 18:27:03.390 BLEChat Central[395:303] Name : Biscuit

2014-07-16 18:27:03.391 BLEChat Central[395:303]
-------------------------------------

2014-07-16 18:27:03.391 BLEChat Central[395:303] Connecting to peripheral with UUID : 308B4C0E-F756-434C-84D4-B474B1C12AD6

2014-07-16 18:27:03.567 BLEChat Central[395:303] Connected to 308B4C0E-F756-434C-84D4-B474B1C12AD6 successful

2014-07-16 18:27:03.582 BLEChat Central[395:303] ->Connected

2014-07-16 18:27:03.747 BLEChat Central[395:303] Length: 2

2014-07-16 18:27:03.747 BLEChat Central[395:303] y

2014-07-16 18:27:03.749 BLEChat Central[395:303] Length: 2

2014-07-16 18:27:03.749 BLEChat Central[395:303] y

2014-07-16 18:27:03.750 BLEChat Central[395:303] Length: 2

2014-07-16 18:27:03.750 BLEChat Central[395:303] i

2014-07-16 18:27:03.814 BLEChat Central[395:303] Length: 2

2014-07-16 18:27:03.814 BLEChat Central[395:303] i

2014-07-16 18:27:03.816 BLEChat Central[395:303] Length: 2

2014-07-16 18:27:03.816 BLEChat Central[395:303] i

2014-07-16 18:27:03.817 BLEChat Central[395:303] Length: 2

2014-07-16 18:27:03.817 BLEChat Central[395:303] i

2014-07-16 18:27:03.818 BLEChat Central[395:303] Length: 2

2014-07-16 18:27:03.818 BLEChat Central[395:303] i
```

I also tried to transmit the data with an adaption of the arduino code:

```
     // uint16_t value = smoothedAX;

     uint16_t value = 123; // fake reading

     BLEMini_write(0x0B);

     BLEMini_write(value >> 8);

     BLEMini_write(value);
```

But then I receive an error message instantly:

```
2014-07-16 18:28:04.930 BLEChat Central[425:303] scanForPeripheralsWithServices

2014-07-16 18:28:04.964 BLEChat Central[425:303] didDiscoverPeripheral

2014-07-16 18:28:04.964 BLEChat Central[425:303] Duplicate UUID found updating...

2014-07-16 18:28:06.932 BLEChat Central[425:303] Stopped Scanning

2014-07-16 18:28:06.932 BLEChat Central[425:303] Known peripherals : 1

2014-07-16 18:28:06.932 BLEChat Central[425:303] List of currently known peripherals :

2014-07-16 18:28:06.932 BLEChat Central[425:303] 0  |  308B4C0E-F756-434C-84D4-B474B1C12AD6

2014-07-16 18:28:06.932 BLEChat Central[425:303] ------------------------------------

2014-07-16 18:28:06.933 BLEChat Central[425:303] Peripheral Info :

2014-07-16 18:28:06.933 BLEChat Central[425:303] UUID : 308B4C0E-F756-434C-84D4-B474B1C12AD6

2014-07-16 18:28:06.933 BLEChat Central[425:303] Name : Biscuit

2014-07-16 18:28:06.933 BLEChat Central[425:303] -------------------------------------

2014-07-16 18:28:06.933 BLEChat Central[425:303] Connecting to peripheral with UUID : 308B4C0E-F756-434C-84D4-B474B1C12AD6

2014-07-16 18:28:06.975 BLEChat Central[425:303] Connected to 308B4C0E-F756-434C-84D4-B474B1C12AD6 successful

2014-07-16 18:28:06.991 BLEChat Central[425:303] ->Connected

2014-07-16 18:28:07.131 BLEChat Central[425:303] Length: 2

2014-07-16 18:28:07.132 BLEChat Central[425:303] (null)

2014-07-16 18:28:07.133 BLEChat Central[425:303] An uncaught exception was raised

2014-07-16 18:28:07.134 BLEChat Central[425:303] -[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument

2014-07-16 18:28:07.134 BLEChat Central[425:303] (

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e5725c __exceptionPreprocess + 172

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88243e75 objc_exception_throw + 43

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e5710c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204

3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e26def mutateError + 159

4   BLEChat Central                     0x00000001000054d1 -[RBLAppDelegate bleDidReceiveData:length:] + 257

5   BLEChat Central                     0x0000000100004cb2 -[BLE peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:] + 770

6   CoreBluetooth                       0x00007fff884b4089 -[CBCentralManager xpcConnection:didReceiveMsg:args:] + 101

7   CoreBluetooth                       0x00007fff884bd88b __34-[CBXpcConnection handleMsg:args:]_block_invoke + 81

8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff884c81bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12

9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff884c528d _dispatch_client_callout + 8

10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff884ccef0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333

11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82dbe4f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9

12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82d79714 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636

13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82d78e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309

14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff877cea0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226

15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff877ce7b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479

16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff877ce5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65

17  AppKit                              0x00007fff833f624e _DPSNextEvent + 1434

18  AppKit                              0x00007fff833f589b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122

19  AppKit                              0x00007fff833e999c -[NSApplication run] + 553

20  AppKit                              0x00007fff833d4783 NSApplicationMain + 940

21  BLEChat Central                     0x0000000100005122 main + 34

22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff87eea5fd start + 1

)

2014-07-16 18:28:07.135 BLEChat Central[425:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'

*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e5725c __exceptionPreprocess + 172

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88243e75 objc_exception_throw + 43

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e5710c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204

3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e26def mutateError + 159

4   BLEChat Central                     0x00000001000054d1 -[RBLAppDelegate bleDidReceiveData:length:] + 257

5   BLEChat Central                     0x0000000100004cb2 -[BLE peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:] + 770

6   CoreBluetooth                       0x00007fff884b4089 -[CBCentralManager xpcConnection:didReceiveMsg:args:] + 101

7   CoreBluetooth                       0x00007fff884bd88b __34-[CBXpcConnection handleMsg:args:]_block_invoke + 81

8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff884c81bb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12

9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff884c528d _dispatch_client_callout + 8

10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff884ccef0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333

11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82dbe4f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9

12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82d79714 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636

13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82d78e75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309

14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff877cea0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226

15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff877ce7b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479

16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff877ce5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65

17  AppKit                              0x00007fff833f624e _DPSNextEvent + 1434

18  AppKit                              0x00007fff833f589b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122

19  AppKit                              0x00007fff833e999c -[NSApplication run] + 553

20  AppKit                              0x00007fff833d4783 NSApplicationMain + 940

21  BLEChat Central                     0x0000000100005122 main + 34

22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff87eea5fd start + 1

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

According to the Xcode-Debugger the bug should be in the following two methods:

```
-(void) bleDidReceiveData:(unsigned char *)data length:(int)length
{
    NSLog(@"Length: %d", length);

    data[length] = 0;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSLog(@"%@", str);

    static NSMutableString *message;

    if (message == nil)
        message = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

    [message appendString:str];
    [message appendString:@"\n"];

    self.textView.string = message;
    [self.textView scrollRangeToVisible: NSMakeRange(self.textView.string.length, 0)];
}
```

and

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    unsigned char data[20];

    static unsigned char buf[512];
    static int len = 0;
    NSInteger data_len;

    if (!error)
    {
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@RBL_CHAR_TX_UUID]])
        {
            data_len = characteristic.value.length;
            [characteristic.value getBytes:data length:data_len];

            if (data_len == 20)
            {
                memcpy(&buf[len], data, 20);
                len += data_len;

                if (len >= 64)
                {
                    [[self delegate] bleDidReceiveData:buf length:len];
                    len = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (data_len < 20)
            {
                memcpy(&buf[len], data, data_len);
                len += data_len;

                [[self delegate] bleDidReceiveData:buf length:len];
                len = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"updateValueForCharacteristic failed!");
    }
}
```

Might be the solution to add following code in the OSX app? And if so, where do I have to put it?

```
UInt16 value;
UInt16 pin;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=3) {
  pin = data[i];
  value = data[i+2] | data[i+1] << 8;
  NSLog(@"Pin: %d", pin);
  NSLog(@"Value %d",value);
}
```

I tried to look for a solution for three days but I haven't been able to solve the problem. It would be really nice if you could help me :)

Thanks a lot in advance and cheers!

Comment: >> is a right shift operation.  When you apply right shift 8 to a 8 bit value (i.e. less than 256) you will get 0 - which seems like it is resulting in the nil append error.  What is the value of `smoothedAX` in your first test?  How do you know that y and i aren't correct?

Comment: The value of smoothedAX lies between -300 and + 300 - this info comes from the Arduino serial monitor.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you had a 16 bit value.  Strangely you have an unsigned int but are getting signed values.  Anyway the method you are using for sending the 16 bit value as two bytes is correct.  You need to examine the code that is receiving the data to determine why you are getting a crash

Comment: I figured out that according to the Xcode-Debugger the bug is in the lines   [message appendString:str]    and    [[self delegate] bleDidReceiveData:buf length:len]    Could the solution be the answer of following question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207727/how-can-i-receive-simple-integer-values-over-bluetooth-in-ios If so, where should I implement this part? Thanks @Paulw11

Comment: Yes, that answer looks like the right way to re-create the 16 bit value.  Your problem seems to be that the same code you are using is designed to receive text strings, not binary data.  If you update your question to include the method with the code from your comment I can probably suggest a change

Comment: You need to show the code for the method where the crash is occuring

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57538/discussion-between-mateo-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only sending the two bytes then the simplest approach is -

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    int smoothedAX;

    if (!error)
    {
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@RBL_CHAR_TX_UUID]])
        {
            if (characteristic.value.length == 2) {
               const char *data=[characteristic.value bytes];
               smoothedAX=data[0] <<8 | data[1];
            }
            else {
               NSLog(@"Received %ld bytes",characteristic.value.length);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"updateValueForCharacteristic failed!");
    }
}
```

You will need to do something useful with smoothedAX - probably pass it to another method

Comment: You need to provide the exception. I am guessing it is an out of range error because I don't check whether two bytes were received. I can update my answer shortly